# Where do I find bootsect.exe for Windows 2012 R2 machine running on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation, windows-server-2012-r2

I need bootsect.exe utility to fix one of my EC2 volumes (make it bootable again after I removed admin account with sysprep) but I don't have access to 2012 R2 setup disk where it's supposed to come from. Googling doesn't help much. Where do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootsect.exe is part of the Windows 2012 ADK and can be downloaded here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652

Comment: Which component of the ADK is needed to install Bootsect.exe?

Comment: It will be somewhere like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\BCDBoot on the machine where the ADK is installed.

Comment: No, I meant which component box in the installer needs to be ticked since the major component is a 3Gb install which is a lot for a single executable!